# appium-doctor --android returns error AppiumDoctor ✖ android could NOT be found in /Library/Android/sdk! on macOS

Tags: appium, mobile-automation, android-automation, mac

Team,
Facing error while executing `appium-doctor --android`

> AppiumDoctor  ✖ android could NOT be found in /Library/Android/sdk!

Interestingly,

- Location exist with appropriate permission
- Android SDK exist on same location. Verified location in Android studio
- ANDROID_HOME is set correctly under environment variable
- Detected correctly by appium-doctor as well

What could be causing this error? Anybody is having working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed :

Spend little more time in googling the cause and solution if any. But few trick resolved this error.

1. Add below lines in your `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/33.0.0:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/33.0.0/bin:$PATH
```

2. Android studio > SDK manager > SDK Tools > Uncheck "Hide Obsolete Packages" option & install all of them
3. Reopen terminal or `source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/50312) helped me to resolve the error -

```
android could NOT be found in /Users/{user_name}/Library/Android/sdk!
```

**Sharing a screenshot for helping the community**

[image]